# Finding ratio of length of radii from ratio of areas?

Tags: ratio

**The Question**: A central angle of two concentric circles is $\frac{3\pi}{14}$. The area of the large sector is twice the area of the small sector. What is the ratio of the lengths of the radii of the two circles?

Answer: 0.71:1

The answer I end up with is $\sqrt{2}$:$1$, instead of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$: 1 (which I'm assuming is how they got 0.71). My book says the angle measure is superfluous, and that "areas of similar figures are proportional to the squares of linear measures associated with those figures". Using the similar figures property, this was my answer:

if $r_2$ = radius of larger circle and $r_1$ = radius of smaller circle and likewise for $a_2$ and $a_1$, then ($\frac{r_2}{r_1}$)$^2$ = $\frac{a_2}{a_1}$. Since $\frac{a_2}{a_1}$ = 2, taking the root of both sides yields $\sqrt{2}$ = $\frac{r_2}{r_1}$. Any explanation would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: What are  you actually asking?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ - maybe this is where you are going wrong. Plus the order of the ratio.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics Sorry if it wasn't clear, I just didn't know why my answer was wrong/how they got their answer.

Comment: They have written as the answer the ratio of the smaller to the larger, and you have found the ratio of the larger to the smaller.

Comment: @DavidQuinn My answer was sqrt(2):1, and theirs was 0.71:1.

Comment: Explanation of what?  Everything you said is perfectly correct.  The ratio of the long to short radius is root (2) to 1.  The ratio of the short radius to long is 1/root (2) $\approx$ .71 to 1 (and *SHAME* on your book for thinking that was a acceptable answer, especially at the teaching level).  And shame on your book for not specifying whether it wanted the ratio of the long to short, or the short to long.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Sorry, got super confused there! You're right, thanks!

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! This had me so confused, didn't even think about the possibility that they might have done it the other way!

Comment: r2/r1= root (2).  r1/r2 = 1/root (2) =.71.  No harm no foul.  But I'm not going to be taking your book to the prom after that sort of shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify which radius comes first in the proportion.  The book answer gives $r_1:r_2=\frac {\sqrt 2}2:1$ while you are saying $r_2:r_1=\sqrt 2:1$.  You agree with the book but present the data in the opposite order.  I also object strongly to saying $\frac {\sqrt 2}2=0.71$ but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

let r = radius of the smaller circle and
     R = radius of the larger circle.
We will get R:r= √2: 1.
Since the order in taking which radius first we can take 
            r:R =1:√2
          or r/R=1/√2= 0.707
          i.e., r:R=0.707:1

```
            r:R=0.71:1
```